# JPQL Update Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUESTION_GROUP_TEXT")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = EntityUtils.NamedQuery.UPDATE_QUESTION_GROUP_TEXT,
                query = "UPDATE QuestionGroupText T SET T.localizedText.content = :content WHERE T.generatedId = :generatedId")
})
public class QuestionGroupText implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "GENERATED_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String generatedId = generateId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCALIZED_TEXT_ID", nullable = false)
    private LocalizedText localizedText;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

This query: `UPDATE QuestionGroupText T SET T.localizedText.content = :content WHERE T.generatedId = :generatedId` does not work, it throws:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set CONTENT='Question Label' where GENERATED_ID='AD78F9B5E2A146D9AB9D94096DA835B' at line 1
```

There must be something wrong with this part of the query: `T.localizedText.content`, is there any way I can change it to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to rewrite the query that I needed:

```
UPDATE LocalizedText L SET L.content = :content WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T FROM QuestionGroupText T WHERE T.localizedText.id = L.id AND T.generatedId = :generatedId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to me you are trying to update a foreign key from this table.

I think the correct way is to update LocalizedText instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute localizedText is a foreignkey to your Table for Entity LocalizedText

Your query tries to set :content (whatever type this may be) to a foreign key column. This does not work. Do you have the table LocalizedText  defined?

What you can do:

1. set a new ID to your attribute localizedText
2. Or update Table LocalizedText with content

Please note: You have to set @Id annotation inside QuestionGroupText when you want an Id.

generatedId seams to be the right place